# Surface Pro 4 no longer connects to Bluetooth mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, microsoft-surface-pro

After the January 2016 firmware update for the Surface Pro 4, I can no longer use my Bluetooth Microsoft arc mouse. The Bluetooth settings show that it is paired, yet I get no response. I cannot remove the mouse using *Manage Bluetooth Devices* as this action fails every time. The device is also not found when in pairing mode.
Is there another way to remove the device manually?

Answer (score 0):

hold windows key and R type in  services.msc and select services.

The dialog box that opens has a long list of stuff but look for BLUETOOTH SUPPORT SERVICE. Double click to open. Make sure it is AUTOMATIC. Go to the LOG tab. Choose THIS ACCOUNT and type in LOCAL SERVICE. A list of password (a 15-dot string) would appear. Delete all the password in the PASSWORD and under CONFIRM. Choose Okay.

It will ask you to restart the service. Once restarted, turn on your bluetooth adaptor again. Put your mouse in pairing mode and add the mouse.

See if this works for you.

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. I removed the mouse via device manager and viewing hidden devices under blue tooth. But at the moment I cannot see new devices when scanning for them. I will try with some other blue tooth devices later, but I can see the mouse is in pairing mode when looking for devices on my phone.

Comment: Fixed it - it looks like the Marvell AVASTAR Bluetooth Radio Adapter was disabled in Device Manager after the firmware update. Restarted it and it all works. The pen must use something different to connect then as this was not affected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to get how to get blue-tooth working again on Surface Pro3, similar to the way John mentioned in a comment. For me Bluetooth had disappeared from all the usual places and was "hidden" when reviewing device manager.

Go back to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and re-enable the wireless connection which references Marvell AVASTAR and it should work. Bluetooth network connection will be showing, bluetooth option showing again under PC and Device, and any previously paired Bluetooth devices should be working again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same thing. "Bluetooth Settings" page tells me that my Arc Mouse is Paired with my Surface Pro 4 (Windows 10 and fully up to date) but the mouse doesn't work. I believe a similar thing has happened to my pen too because the button won't trigger the Notebook, but the pen is paired.

Before I go any further I will say that when I try to 'pair' a bluetooth device with my SP4 I seem to have more success when I select "Add Bluetooth or Other Devices" before making my bluetooth device discoverable than if I do this the other way round. Not sure why this might be.

I have managed to get both arc touch mouse and pen working again as follows:

1. Remove/uninstall all Arc Touch mouse (and pen) references from the Bluetooth section in Device Manager (which can be accessed from the Bluetooth settings page) - use the local menu and 'uninstall device'
2. Remove Arc Touch mouse (and pen) from the "Mouse, Keyboard & Pen" section in Bluetooth Settings window
3. Remove Arc Touch mouse (and pen) from the "Other Devices" section in Bluetooth Settings window (several copies appeared here after unsuccessful attempts to re-'pair')
4. Remove batteries from mouse.
5. Restart Surface Pro 4.
6. "Add Bluetooth or Other Device" from Bluetooth settings page
7. Repower arc touch mouse and press bluetooth button on underside (blue LED blinks when ready)
8. Arc Touch mouse should appear in the list of devices on screen. Select. Wait for the 'mouse is undergoing additional configuration' message to appear and disappear before saying "Done" (Repeat for pen if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

For Surface Pro 4, here is what I did when I had the problem with Bluetooth no longer showing up:

1. Swipe left to get action center
2. Click on All Settings button
3. Make sure you are at the parent menu (you will see a list with System,    Devices, Network & Internet and more in a column)
4. Scroll down and click Update & Security (on my Surface, the last choice)
5. Click on Troubleshoot (about halfway down)
6. Scroll down to Find and Fix Problems
7. Click on Bluetooth
8. Click on "Run the Troubleshooter" button
9. Tell it what you want to do (now that I've fixed mine, I don't see the options).

That fixed it for me. Hope the same is true for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Under Bluetooth settings, the mouse said "connected" but it would not move the cursor or click at all. I was able to un-pair it, but each time it reconnected it wouldn't work. It also still said "connected" even when I turned the mouse off...

The way I fixed it was by going into the device manager and un-installing the mouse. Then I restarted the surface. When it came back on, I opened the Bluetooth menu and the mouse was there again under the "other devices" category... weird. But, this time it only said "paired" and when I turned the mouse on, that changed to "connected" and the mouse worked again!